# Detect onHover being complete on a Chart.js doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Chart.js doughnut chart (v2.7.1) and I am looking to set the class of an external element when the user hovers over the relevant chart element

I can use the `onHover` event within the `options.hover` of the chart

```
 hover: {
                    onHover: function (evt, item) {
                        if (item.length) {
                            var index = item[0]._index;
                            var legendElement = $(#get element based on index#);
                            legendElement.addClass('active');
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and this sets the class on the element (`legendElement`) perfectly but I need to be able to remove the class I set from the element when the user is no longer hovering over the element

Am I using the correct approach? Is there a way to detect that the onHover is complete or that the segment is no longer in focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you defining an "events" property apart from the "onHover" property? If you add "mouseout" to the list, the "onHover" function will be called in both cases. Check out the documentation for this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html

An example code that might work:

```
options: {
   events: ["mousemove", "mouseout"],
   onHover: function (evt, item) {

       if (item.length) {
           var index = item[0]._index;
           var legendElement = $(#get element based on index#);
           if(evt.type == "mousemove"){
             legendElement.addClass('active');
           }else{
             legendElement.removeClass('active');
           }

       }
   }
}
```